# Turning Ubuntu 12.04 entirely Grey/B&W/Monoscale

Tags: 12.04, compiz, color-management

Does anyone know a way to change the color settings of the entire display to grey (or saturation to zero)? I have compiz Settings Manager installed if that helps but don't know how to do it there.

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing around with the "Opacity, Brightness and Saturation" option under Accessibility in ccsm and have been able to set all windows to a saturation of 0, but the Dock and Dash don't seem to be affected by the change. A work around might be to change the Icon set to one of the High contrast versions that exist on the system or by finding one of your liking on the internet.

Here's how. CCSM-> Accessibility-> (Enable) Opacity, Brightness and Saturation. This will cause Compiz to have a little fit, give it time and it will repair itself.

In the OBaS settings go to the saturation tab. Under "Window specific settings" click New, in the next dialog box enter "type=any" without quotes, and set the Window values to 0. Click close and the results should be instantaneous.

Comment: It doesn't change anything when I implement what you've said.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with gamma:

```
> xgamma -gamma 0.9
```