# How to make ubuntu black and white?

Tags: unity, 13.04, themes, icons

This might be a somewhat strange question.

I had an argument with a windows person and I told him that linux is so much more customization then he told me to prove it and I told him .....
Now I need to make ubuntu black and white  to prove linux is better

I want to make ubuntus menus icons, folder icons etc... except the running apps black and white

something like this ??

[image]

And stock icons.

So can any one point me in a direction I need to go

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Bump. Awesome example for such an argument.

Comment: Hope some one will help me out :)
or my face is going to become really red

Comment: I seem to recall a QnA on this and the answer involved compiz. If I find it, this question may be a dupe of that.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/136496/turning-ubuntu-12-04-entirely-grey-bw-monoscale but the person who asked the question didn't accept any answer :(

Comment: thank you for your afforded
 I do not think I want to do that :) right now I think I am going to try batch converting icons see were it goes  
/usr/share/icons

Comment: @Levan You have very fancy wallpaper ...would you like to share the link of your wallpaper ?

Comment: That is not a wallpaper any way here
http://www.comfortfurniture.com.sg/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/artistic-colors-54567.jpg
or

http://www.comfortfurniture.com.sg/designers-tips/explore-with-colors/attachment/artistic-colors-54567/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an black and white icon pack

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbKOD.jpg)

http://levan27.deviantart.com/art/Ater-370973051?ga_submit_new=10%253A1368280191&ga_type=edit&ga_changes=1&ga_recent=1

Answer (score 1):

You could filter all Icons with a black and white filter, although that would be a lot of work

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I am not quite sure how that would work I tried that in the end most icons did not show up any more :D some one should tell me what format is it tolerant to and what color model should I use and where to place all of this new icons