# How can I make ubuntu completely black and white?

Tags: unity, themes

I installed `Ubuntu Tweak` for the black and white theme. But that theme only made icons black and white. I want complete black and white feel for Ubuntu, how can I get it?

Complete means when I play an RGB video, it can be displayed in black and white.

I read:

- http://ubuntu-tweak.com/
- [How to make ubuntu black and white?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293512/how-to-make-ubuntu-black-and-white)
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2143868

Comment: I very much doubt that this will be possible. You will need to modify the various programs you use yourself. For example, what if you open an image file, would you expect that to be black and white as well? I think your best solution is to buy an old black and white monitor.

Comment: @terdon I littele agree with you.. ;)

Comment: The concept you're looking for is the saturation (as in HSV / HSL color spaces). Check this question to get a complete black and white Ubuntu: (works on 16.04 and 16.10) http://askubuntu.com/questions/455900/how-to-reduce-the-saturation-of-of-laptop-monitor-in-ubuntu-14-04